# When does it become "long enough" to use the term "always"?

Tags: time

[This BBC page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-39333376) caught my eye: *"Physicists had always believed"*. Except they hadn't. Its a very recent belief, probably under 30 - 40 years old.

We often use "always" without thinking, to make a point or  as shorthand for "some kind of  significant time". But what sort of criteria do people instinctively use for "always"? At what point do people tend to slip from a specific time, or some measure of time, to the claim that its always been so?

For example, one would never say, "England has *always* been at peace with Germany", even though it is at peace and has been for far longer than the above statement (1945 vs 1980s - 1990s?).

Clearly there's something about the context -- either of the subject matter or the question - which has an effect. But do we know more?

Note, I'm not after examples so much. Examples probably exist all over the place for usage. More looking for research or understanding what sort of criteria are being used, when that decision to use "always" happens, if there is any. Its probably related to didactic or intent or sense of time or... but I have no real idea and am curious if anyone knows.

Comment: If you're 21 and always had red hair, that's all of 21 years and still makes sense. But it's not very always. Also, antiques earn that name after 100 years.

Comment: That would be "since it first existed". It would make sense not to attribute a state or property to something before it existed. Similar statement: "That door has always creaked" or "that kitten has always been drowsy", one might say that after a time but not the day after it started to exist)

Comment: That is well said.

Comment: Because of this grossly inaccurate yet common use of always (and never), the emotionally intelligent monitor themselves before saying "You always say no" or "I never exaggerate on my tax returns."

Comment: @Stilez Similarly in the particle article, physicists had always (ever since they had any kind of realistic possibility of having any kind of opinion on the matter) believed whatever it was they believed. That is, throughout more or less the entire existence of their believing anything, this was what they'd believed. It's like saying “I always thought Catherine Zeta-Jones was Spanish” (a surprisingly common belief, as it happens): clearly you didn't think so before you'd heard of her, but once you knew who she was and formed a belief, that was it.

Comment: In a previous life I developed specifications for computer programs and I came to realize that to many end users "always" meant "for the past two weeks."

Comment: Well. Um. I can say "I will always love you" right after having been in love with you for all of two minutes. And I can say it even if I know full well that I will get decapitated two minutes later. I am frankly not quite sure what your question has to do with English at all. (Would you not have the exact same question if we were speaking Russian or French?) Anyway. Sorry for the rambling. I think what I'm really trying to say with this comment is: the official limit is exactly two minutes.

Comment: In this context, "always" is taken to mean "there was never any doubt about it (until now)". It's not correct to the letter, but that is the meaning that is intended (and commonly understood, in my opinion).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: If we close this topic because the source is not verified to be using grammatically correct English, then we should start closing a **massive** amount of questions. Literally every question with a grammatical mistake in the example, when the OP does not claim to have written it themselves but are merely asking for clarification. ELU includes _usage_ in the title. The BBC used English, in a manner that sounds weird to the OP. This seems perfectly on topic to ask whether the usage is correct (BBC is right) or not (the OP is right).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: If this were about a **headline**, I would agree with you. But this is found in the **body** of the article, which is expected to use grammatically correct English.

Comment: @Flater I didn't see the link (too much ambient light), so I missed the fact that the belief seems correct. I'd expect 'Physicists _have_ always believed' here. Your answer makes good points. I was concerned about the degree of departure from the absolutely precisionist reading (which, as you say, doesn't make cosmological sense anyway). Register makes a big difference to the degree of hyperbole considered acceptable.  'My sister's always teased me' can mean say 7 years, and 'My sister's always teasing me' can mean 'every two weeks'. I'd expect 'Switzerland has always remained neutral' ...

Comment: to mean 'without exception since it became a nation'.

Answer (score 0):

> This BBC page caught my eye: "**Physicists had always believed**". Except they hadn't. Its a very recent belief, probably under 30 - 40 years old.

In this context, "always" is taken to mean "there was never any doubt about it" (until now).
It's not correct to the literal definition of "always", but that is the meaning that is intended (and commonly understood, in my opinion).

---

### You need to observe the context.

Your context is about subatomic particles and quantum physics. This branch of science has only functionally existed for the last few decades (which is the 30 - 40 year timespan that you are alluding to).

Therefore a sentence such as this:

> "[**Quantum**] physicists had **always** believed  that..."

Should be taken as an equivalent to:

> "**For as long as quantum physics has been a studied field**, those [quantum] physicists have believed that..."

"always" is used for brevity's sake.

---

There are plenty of examples that showcase similar substitutions:

> I have always loved listening to Deep Purple.
>   *From since I first heard about them, I have loved listening to Deep Purple.*
>
> I have always gone to bed before midnight.
>   *For as long as **I can remember**, I have gone to bed before midnight.*
>   **or**
>   *For as long as **I've been alive**, I have gone to bed before midnight.*

---

### *Pedantically:*

*If you extend your line of thinking ("always" is wrong when it is used to refer to a limited timespan), the word "always" could **technically** never be true since time itself has not existed infinitely.*